# How to create/generate WCF RESTful webservice client in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, wcf-rest, restful-architecture

I have a RESTful webservice in WCF.

How can I create/generate a RESTful webservice client for it in Netbeans?

Ultimately, I would like to use it in a JSF web application.

Comment: This problem is beyond JSF. You should ask how to create a webservice client instead of how to invoke a webservice client (which you don't have yet at all) in JSF.

Comment: I improved it further. It's as said *beyond* JSF. A webservice client is not specific to a particular frontend. A webservice client is just reusable on all kinds of frontends. You should ultimately be able to create/run it in a plain vanilla Java application with `main()` method (which allows for much easier testing than a web application, by the way). Once you got that far, just invoke exactly the same code in (post)constructor of a JSF managed bean.

Comment: Because WCF REST service does not provide neither WADL or WSDL 2.0 document describing available resources you will most probably have to write the client yourselves.

Comment: Ok. Thanks i will try on plain java app and then on web. I'm afk right now.